# Change tab page in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change the tabpage in another form using something like this?

```
using (Form frm = new Form())
{
     frm.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
     frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. What is the problem?

Comment: Ensure `tabControl1` being declared as `public` or `internal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the designer page of your form change

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
```

to

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
```

and then

```
using (Form frm = new Form())
{
     frm.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
     frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

should work

Comment: While technically correct, if using Winforms, if I was to give advice about this, I'd advocate to change the `Modifiers` property in the designer, instead of manually modifying the `designer.cs` file.

Comment: Jcl nails it! This will be much better than messing with the designer files! Please consider incorporating it into the answer to make it most useful!